# Controlling class name in the stacktrace

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

Defining classes in javascript as functions makes perfect stack traces:

```
name.space.MyClass = function() {};

name.space.MyClass.prototype.method = function() {
  console.trace();
};

(new name.space.MyClass()).trace();
```

Outputs something like this (in Chrome):

```
name.space.MyClass.method
(anonymous function)
```

I'm wandering if there is any way to have readable stacktraces when you use a function to define a class:

```
registerComponent('my-component', {
  method: function() {}
});
```

Obviously behavior may vary across the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, JavaScript as of ECMAScript 5 has no notion of classes, but I get what you mean.

In order to get good stack traces, you must name the function:

```
registerComponent('my-component', {
  method: function myComponent$_method() {}
});
```

Named function expressions create good stack traces. Personally, I also stick to `new` for now for stack traces, as combining both (`new` with constructor functions, and named function expressions) produce by far the best stack traces in JS at the moment.

Note that this behavior may change for the better in the future.

Comment: Even though it is useful information, it doesn't solve the problem. The point of the `registerComponent` function is to simplify class definition. But if we are required to name each method then, it'll become a burden.

Comment: @pvolok then no, this is the only way unless you can rewrite registerComponent.